# Stopping Dreamweaver from putting .GIT folder/files to my production server

Tags: git, deployment

I'm in the process of teaching myself GIT and using my website to practice. Dreamweaver is my preferred IDE but when I 'PUT' the whole site to my production server it also 'PUT's all the files in the hidden .git directory. I know how to use cloaking for specific file types but is there a way for it to ignore that folder or is my only option to select specific files.

Comment: The `.git` directory and the files inside it are not "github files".

Comment: @torazaburo sorry re-worded question, good point

Comment: This isn't a dreamweaver issue, it sounds like you need to improve your deploy process.

Comment: @Swordfish0321 Yes, maybe. I rely on Dreamweaver PUTing only changed files. I do whole site as it makes sure all dependencies are PUT across. I use CC 2014 that seams much better the CS6 at PUTing all dependant files. Is it better practice to select only changed files at manually PUT them?

Comment: According to a quick scan of the Dreamweaver site, cloaking seems to be apply to specific files and folders as well as filetypes: "Site cloaking enables you to exclude **files and folders** from operations such as Get or Put."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I need to improve my deploy process. But I was able to solve it by:
1. Unhide the .git folder
2. Use Dreamweavers cloaking function.
Maybe one day Adobe will include GITHUB integration.

Answer (score 0):

To be a little more specific:
In Dreamweaver, make sure the Files panel is open for the site you are working on. Click the Refresh button (clockwise pointing arrow circle) to make sure your .git folder is displayed. Right-click on the .git folder. Choose Cloaking/Cloak. The folder icon for that folder will show a red slash through it.

Answer (score -1):

Because you're already using git locally, you should set up a new remote on a server (with `git init --bare`) and push to that remote.

To create the link to that remote:

git remote add production user@server.com:pathtogit

To push to that remote

git push production master

You then should have a script that will automate your deployment when the remote receives some changes (using [git hooks](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks))

This answer is just the beginning of it, you should try to search a bit for yourself